# Why does Django causes my materialize link to appear blue when I hover over them?

Tags: css, django-templates

[image]

as you can see when I hover over the dropdown box the link becomes blue, what could be the cause of this??

I am using Django with this maybe that could be causing problems

I tried it in a document with only the materialize header and it works just fine:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>

<body>
        <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
    <ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
    </ul>
    <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
        <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-trigger" data-target="dropdown1">Dropdown<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
      M.AutoInit()
      $(".dropdown-trigger").dropdown();
      
    </script>
</body>
```

When I combine it with my Django main page it messes up, what should I remove/add?

Main page header:

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Stock Trading Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static "/css/main.css"%}">

        <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
       
    </head>
```

Please let me know if you need anything else :)

Comment: Django does not do anything to styles, so this is css-only question.

Comment: what information would you need to help me here?

Comment: I went through and removed the bootstrap CDN and it works like a charm now.